# How adding extra data product item in plugin easyshop octobercms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I wanted to customize and add some extra data for my site, but I can't find plugins for do that.
I use easyshop plugins and using October CMS

Anybody have suggestion for the plugins? I am still learn about this cms...

Comment: can you please share with us more details about what extra data and where you want to add it ... so we can help you netter

Comment: https://octobercms.com/plugin/pixel-shop 
with this plugin I just can enter usual data like brand name, category, type, short description. but I want add more column and I am looking for plugins to extend for customize more column

Comment: Have you tried item variants? But frankly, if you need extensibility & flexibility this plugin is much more customizable: https://octobercms.com/plugin/offline-mall

Comment: Thx for answer but I can't use item variants. cuz  it just like information of product and I don't want user chose